# Finding numerical solution for nonlinear Poisson-like equation using finite difference method

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-integration, finite-differences

I am trying to use finite difference method to solve for $u(x,t)$ in the equation:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{au}{1+bu},
\end{align}
which is actually part of a system of PDEs. The equation came from the Michaelis-Menten law used in modelling tumor growth where $u(x,t)$ is the oxygen tension. The RHS of the equation can be re-written as follows,
\begin{align}
\frac{au}{1+bu} = \frac{a}{b}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+bu}\right).
\end{align}
The boundary conditions are $\partial u/\partial x = 0$ at $x=0$ and $u(1,t)=0$. Usually, for  Poisson equation $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=f(x)$, which is quite similar to the above, I just do
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2}=f_i,
\end{align}
for each $i=1,...,n$ and re-write the resulting discretised equations in a matrix form
\begin{align}
{\bf Au=b},
\end{align}
and thus manipulate the matrix system (or use any other methods like Gauss-Seidel) to get the solution ${\bf u}$. But, how do I do it for the equation above? I would be very grateful if someone could give me a small hint or point me to some useful reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a non-linear differential equation you cannot expect to obtain a linear system at the end. Think about using a non-linear solver like a Newton solver instead.